# log in codeforces from Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to log me into www.codeforces.com/enter from command line, but in every try, it fails with [403] Response Error.  The prototype of code looks like:

```
import requests
import getpass

base = "http://codeforces.com"
cf_enter = "{base}/{login}".format(base=base, login="enter")

cliente = requests.session()
r = cliente.get(cf_enter)

user = raw_input('User:')
password = getpass.getpass('Password:')

login_data = {
    'action': 'enter',
    'handle': user,
    'password': password,
}
r = cliente.post(cf_enter, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=cf_enter))
print r
```

By the way, with analyzing packages when I do log into website I readed the following cookies, before/after a POST: 'csrf_token", "JSESSIONID", "39ce7", and the payload has 'handle' (username) and 'password'.

**UPDATE1**

After the first comment, I change the code. It works for login, and receive [200] responses, but I want to submit a code, for example, to 'http://codeforces.com/contest/4/submit'

```
import requests
import getpass
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

base = "http://codeforces.com"
cf_enter = "{base}/{login}".format(base=base, login="enter")

cliente = requests.session()
r = cliente.get(cf_enter)
html = r.content
soup = bs(html)
head = soup.head
meta = head.findChildren('meta')
csrf_token = [
    m for m in meta if 'name' in m.attrs and m['name'] == 'X-Csrf-Token']
csrf_token = csrf_token[0]["content"]

print csrf_token # it's working, :)

user = raw_input('User:')
password = getpass.getpass('Password:')

login_data = {
    'csrf_token': csrf_token,
    'action': 'enter',
    'handle': user,
    'password': password,
}

headers = {
    'Referer': cf_enter,
    'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS i686 2268.111.0) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'
}

r = cliente.post(cf_enter, data=login_data, headers=headers)
if r.status_code != 200:
    print 'fail to connect'

type_contest = "contest"
contest_id = '4'
url_submit = "{base}/{type}/{id}/submit".format(
    base=base, type=type_contest, id=contest_id)
print url_submit

# url_submit = url_submit +'?csrf_token={0}'.format(csrf_token)
r = cliente.get(url_submit, headers=headers)
if r.status_code != 200:
    print 'fail to connect', url_submit
else:
    print '[200] ', url_submit


parts = {
    "csrf_token":            csrf_token,
    "action":                "submitSolutionFormSubmitted",
    "contestId": '4',
    "submittedProblemIndex": 'A',
    "source":                open('A.py', "rb"),
    "programTypeId":         '7',
    "sourceFile":            "",
    "_tta":                  "834",
    'handle': user,
    'password': password
}

r = cliente.post(url_submit, files=parts, headers=headers)
print r  # response: [403]
print r.cookies # here, there's nothing , hug?
```

Any suggesting to make it works (?)

Comment: If you check the post request using Chrome developer tools, Firebug or any other relevant tool, you will see there are other parameters being sent in post data - `csrf_token, ftaa, bfaa, _tta`. You can use [bs4](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library to parse `csrf_token and _tta` but `ftaa, bfaa` will need to be parsed using string slicing. Hope that helps.

Comment: Apart from this, you would also like to send the _User-Agent_ string in the headers.

Comment: thanks, I forgot to search into the content of html. It's working. I will put later, the code functional.

Comment: how is it of "ftaa, bfaa will need to be parsed using string slicing. Hope that helps." I don't figure out

Comment: These 2 fields dont appear as html tags, rather those are set inside a javascript in source. If you check source, you will be able to find that.

Comment: yes, I checked like you said, the problem is that if I imported from python, these variables, don't appear at all, If I'm not wrong these variables are generated random and from a javascript execution, doesn't it? Request library doesn't deal with javascript.

Comment: You are right. And we will need to figure out what javascript code is being executed and try to port that to Python.